# Sudden Broken references in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a simple project which I am working on in Visual Studio. Today when I opened it, I found [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRgtF.png). All references are broken and their path is empty. Did I erase a file by mistake? I don't know what I shall do.

Comment: Try and delete the .vs file for that project, it could be corrupted  then restart Visual Studio

Comment: Do  Clean + Rebuild. This happens whenever you make too many changes to your `.csproj` file for NuGet to follow. Sometimes you might need to restart VS too.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

**Method One:**

It is not ruled out that the .vs of the project (this is a hidden file of the project folder) is damaged, so you can find the .vs file of the project and delete it.

**Method Two:**

It may also be that too many nuget packages are referenced to cause confusion in the csproj file, so you can right-click the project in the solution explorer and click Clean and then Rebuild

**Method Three:**

You can open the project's csproj file with Notepad to see if those references make sense. Usually the csproj file will know more about the project than you. You can check to see if its target framework is installed and if it is the .net version you expected. There is also whether the referenced nuget package is the version you expected and so on. These will cause this issue to occur

For example, the target framework of my project is .net 6.0, and now I change it to .net 1.0, the following situation will appear

[image]